# 1c bitrix php, как отправить письмо пользователям с группой "Админ"

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с, framework, sendmail

как отправить письмо пользователям с группой "Админ", может есть готовая функция?

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter = Array("GROUPS_ID" => Array(1));
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by = "NAME"),           ($order = "desc"), $filter);
while ($arUser = $rsUsers->Fetch()) {
    mail($arUser[‘EMAIL’], ...);
}
```